# Как сгенерировать День Рождения?

Tags: java, объекты

Необходимо создать 100 объектов с параметром день рождения. Я так понимаю нужно использовать класс Date, но я не понимаю как использовать его. Есть мысль написать 3 массива: в одном числа, в другом месяцы, в третьем годы, и на рандоме в стринг просто заплюсовать их в таком формате ДД/ММ/ГГГГ. У кого какие идеи есть?

Comment: раз: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985392/generate-random-date-of-birth
два:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35706981/generating-random-date